# Problema con dataset o base adapter en android

Tags: java, android, android-listview, baseadapter

Tengo un problema al representar una lista utilizando un BaseAdapter propio y una clase especifica para el dataset. He probado a crear la lista directamente desde el mainActivity pero el resultado es el mismo así que supuse que el problema estaría en el adapter pero no logro identificarlo. Sea como sea me muestra la lista vacía, a no ser que no le asigne ninguna lista de datos que entonces me da la salida del xml propio de la lista sin editar. Os paso el código del baseAdapter y más abajo pongo el enlace de github por si alguien quiere ver el código entero (ya digo que es posible que el error no esté en el baseAdapter).

```
java
public class AdaptadorLista extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList lista;
    Context context;

    public AdaptadorLista(ArrayList lista, Context context) {
        this.lista = lista;
        this.context = context;

    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return lista.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return lista.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       /* if (convertView==null){
            convertView=LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_lista, parent,false);
        }
        HolderAdicional holder=new HolderAdicional(convertView);
        Version vers= (Version) this.getItem(position);
        holder.getLogo().setImageResource(vers.getCabecera());
        holder.getNombre().setText(vers.getNombre());

        return convertView; */
        HolderAdicional holder;

        if (convertView==null){
            convertView= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_lista,parent,false);
            holder=new HolderAdicional(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (HolderAdicional) convertView.getTag();

            Version vers= (Version) lista.get(position);
            holder.getNombre().setText(vers.getNombre());
            holder.getLogo().setImageResource(vers.getCabecera());
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    class HolderAdicional{
        TextView nombre;
        ImageView logo;

        public HolderAdicional(View view){
            nombre=view.findViewById(R.id.txtVersion);
            logo=view.findViewById(R.id.imgVersion);
        }

        public TextView getNombre() {
            return nombre;
        }

        public ImageView getLogo() {
            return logo;
        }

    }
}
```

https://github.com/marcosmrtnz/practicaVersiones

Answer (score 0):

Veo en tu MainActivity que estas haciendo:

```
private void rellenarLista() {
    listaVersiones.setAdapter(adaptadorLista);
    arrayVersiones=dataSet.newInstance().listadoDataSet();
    adaptadorLista.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

pero en ese metodo no asignas el arrayVersiones al adapter, prueba asignar ese array al adapter despues de instanciarla.

---

En el adapter cuando creas el holder tambien tienes un problema, estas llenando los holders solo si estos ya existen pero si los acabas de crear no los llenas con ningun dato. Yo lo cambiaria de esta forma:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    HolderAdicional holder;
    if (convertView==null){
        convertView= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_lista,parent,false);
        holder=new HolderAdicional(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (HolderAdicional) convertView.getTag();
    }
    Version vers= (Version) lista.get(position);
    holder.getNombre().setText(vers.getNombre());
    holder.getLogo().setImageResource(vers.getCabecera());

    return convertView;
}
```